# What would this Classic asp code look like in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I have to convert some logic of an old Classic ASP site into an asp.net project.  I am having trouble understanding some function which is responsible for posting data.

Here is the function in Classic ASP:

```
<%Function PostHTTP(strURL, strBody, strErrTemplate)
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
Dim objHTTP, strResult

  Set objHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    strResult = Replace(strErrTemplate, "%1", Err.Number)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%2", Err.Description)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%3", "Init::" & Err.Source)
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    PostHTTP = strstrResult
    Exit Function
  End If

  With objHTTP
    .Open "POST", strURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setTimeouts 30000, 30000, 60000, 240000
    .send strBody

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      strResult = Replace(strErrTemplate, "%1", Err.Number)
      strResult = Replace(strResult, "%2", Err.Description)
      strResult = Replace(strResult, "%3", "Post::" & Err.Source)
    Else
      strResult = .responseText
    End If
  End With

' Response.Write "strResult: " & strResult
'Response.End


  If Err.Number > 0 Then
    strResult = Replace(strErrTemplate, "%1", Err.Number)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%2", Err.Description)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%3", Err.Source)
  ElseIf Len(strResult) = 0 Then
    strResult = Replace(strErrTemplate, "%1", 2000)
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%2", "No response received from remote server.")
    strResult = Replace(strResult, "%3", "PostHTTP")
  End If

  PostHTTP = strResult
  Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

What would this look like in asp.net?

ps: I have tried my own posting function, but clearly missed something, as mine does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main task of POST would be quite simple if you use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. For example,

```
// Form URL and POST-DATA
...
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string strResult = wc.UploadString(strURL, strBody);
}
...
```

For more granular control, you can use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class.

**EDIT**: here's the example code for `WebRequest` because it appears that you need to specify the timeout value which is not possible with `WebClient`

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Timeout = 240000; // set timeout
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    // write to the body of the POST request
    writer.Write(strBody);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The same thing here happens as with my own method.  When waiting for the result, in this line of code "string strResult = wc.UploadString(strUrl, strBody);", the operation times out after a minutue.  The URI I am using is for example, http://10.0.0.1:4321, for posting to. Where does the "Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")" fit in?

Comment: @AndrewKemp, ServerXMLHTTP was the API meant for COM clients such as ASP for making HTTP requests. `WebClient`/`WebRequest` are equivalent (or perhaps better) in .NET world. Only thing is that ASP code is specifying various timeout values - the last one (240 seconds) is for getting response. Unfortunately, webclient does not allow specifying the timeout so you need to use webrequest. See my edit in the answer for example code. Also make sure to include protocol (http) in URL and you may need to increase time-out value.

Comment: I have checked that the (http) protocol is added to the URL, and it indeed is.  The operation times out when I try to read the response, as can be seen in my edit above in your response. (Please see edit above).  Maybe I am missing something in the post that can cause no response to be returned?

Comment: @AndrewKemp, have you tried increasing the time-out with the `webrequest` code? If the ASP code works then .NET code should also work. May be it's the issue from server side (where you are posting) - you can easily simulate the post request from tool such as fiddler (or firebug) - capture the successful request from ASP code and compare it with .NET request.